# How to go on game play screen direct after game over in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am making a car racing game using Libgdx framework, In which when game is over there is a retry button on game over screen and by click on that button go to game play screen on which I want to restart my game but its not happen and the screen shown on game play screen is the last when game is over.

```
private void updateGameOver() {

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if(OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(resumeButtonBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)){
            state = GAME_RUNNING;
            return;
        }
```

}

```
}
private void presentGameOver() {

    spriteBatch.draw(Assets.retryButtonRegion, 480 / 2 - 183 / 2, 800 / 2 - 185, 183, 90);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the state to running the instance of all game elements for example car, in your case, is not reset.

You need to call constructor of your game screen

```
private void updateGameOver() {
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    if(OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(resumeButtonBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)){
        game.setscreen(new GameScreen(game,batcher));
        return;
    }
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: thanks Kumar Saurabh for your reply.According to you I have changed my code and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Clicklistener to the Button and implement your method there. Take a look at the [Sceen2D wiki](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#InputListener)

Else check if you even get a value out there. So add a logger inside your If statement and check if you get a log. (`Gdx.app.log("","")`)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but I have already resolve my problem.